# Tcpdump - counting outgoing and incoming ump packets

Tags: sockets, udp, timeout, tcpdump, packet-capture

Is it possible with `tcpdump` to count (for some set up time) the number of outgoing and incoming UDP packets?

I don't have much experience in `tcpdump`, so an advice how to do that would be very helpful. 
I read that a `timeout` commend is good if I want to stop a process after some given time, so I was thinking about just stopping `tcpdump` after my time. But how I can count the number of outgoing and incoming packets and filter only UDP packets?

Answer (score 0):

To count outgoing UDP packets, run `tcpdump -Q out udp > outgoing` and count the number of lines of the `outgoing` file.

To count incoming UDP packets, run `tcpdump -Q in udp > incoming` and count the number of lines of the `incoming` file.